# Grab a branch from a repo and add it to another repo

Tags: git, branch

Pardon for this noob question but I got no idea on how to do it..

So, I have 2 repos - repoA and repoB
How do I 'install' a branch called feature/for-repoB which was in repoA and add/merge it into repoB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[please refer to comments]

simply

```
git remote add <repoA>
git checkout <repoA/feature-for-repoB>
git merge <branch in repoB>
```

resolve conflict then git add, then commit

---

[old answer]

I think you are trying to merge two repos, A and B.

You can use`git checkout --orphan YourBranchName` in repoB, to create a empty branch (feature/for-repoB). And add files from repoA into this branch.

Then merge them.

Please look at the --orphan option at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/1.7.3.1
and remember to backup your original repos.

Comment: Just wondering if there is a need for me to do a `git remote add`?

Comment: it's not necessary, and I think it'll make it a bit more complicate. If you want to merge two repos from remote and update to repoB, you can do it locally (clone repoA, and copy all into the orphan branch)

Comment: Hmm, I am not exactly 'merging' the two repos, rather I was asked to take from this branch in repoA... By the way, what do you mean by "add files from repoA into this branch" - does this means after creating this `orphan` branch, I need to manually copy/paste the files?

Comment: I misunderstood. If that's the case, you can `git remote add`, checkout feature/for-repoB, then merge

Comment: Was wondering just before I did any `git merge`, do I need to do any `git add/commit/push`? I asked this because as I did a `git status`, it wasn't showing me any untracked files, so does this means that I can merge it straight to repoB master branch? I am being paranoid as I do not wished to screw up, especially the repoA

Comment: yep, because you are on new branch with commits from feature/for-repoB. all things are recorded, you can merge right away

Comment: Sweet.. I had thought I may be wrong as I am used to the `git add/commit/push` then the `checkout/merge` methods... The steps you mentioned won't screw up anything in repoA, right?

Comment: yes, it's a local clone of branch in repoA, and you want to merge into a branch in repoB. so repoA is intact, and as long as you don't push to repoA or repoB, it's alright